# how to update a value on tkinter screen?

Tags: python, tkinter

i use tkinter, in one part of my code , i show battery percentage on screen and i use psutil module,

```
charging = tk.Label(DOWN_LEFT,bg='#0000CD',font=('Acumin Variable Concept',45,'bold '))
charging.place(x=420,y=60)

def battery():
    battery = psutil.sensors_battery()
    charging.config(text=f'{battery.percent}%')
battery()
```

everything is ok, until the battery percentage increases or decreses, but my value on the tkniter screen does not. do you have any idea???

Comment: You would need to call `battery()` occasionally, to update the displayed value.  Putting `charging.after(1000, battery)` inside the function would update it once per second, for example.

Comment: what do you mean occasionally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `root.after(ms, func)` function and make sure you have separate names for the function `battery` and the variable `battery`. For now the variable is b. The Interval is 1000 in the `root.after` function meaning that it checks every second. You can change that if you want. It's in milliseconds. This code is an example of what I just mentioned above.

```
import psutil
root = tk.Tk()

charging = tk.Label(root , text='', bg='#0000CD',font=('Acumin Variable Concept',45,'bold '))
charging.place(x=420,y=60)
def battery():
    b = psutil.sensors_battery()
    charging.config(text=f'{b.percent}%')
    root.after(1000, battery)
battery()

root.mainloop()
```

Hopefully this works for you.